# Kali Hydra SSL issue, xHydra (GUI version of Hydra) works just fine

Tags: linux, ssl, kali-linux, openssl

I am getting the following error when running Hydra:

```
starting at 2017-02-14 14:51:37
[ERROR] Compiled without OPENSSL support, module not available!
```

Running simple command, ran the same in xHydra, and it is able to complete successfully.

```
which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

Please recommend how to re-compile hydra with openssl lib.

```
which hydra
/usr/local/bin/hydra
```

I am running Kali Linux, Hydra 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

First find the source code.

(https://is.gd/LlS5Sy) - Example search

Once located you must download it (in the case clone with git)

```
git clone https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra
```

then go into the directory

```
cd thc-hydra
```

then ensure you have the needed dependencies (in the README.md)

```
apt-get install libssl-dev libssh-dev libidn11-dev libpcre3-dev \
             libgtk2.0-dev libmysqlclient-dev libpq-dev libsvn-dev \
             firebird2.1-dev libncp-dev
```

Then you want to compile and install so:

```
apt-get purge hydra hydra-gtk #Get rid of old install
./configure --help #Get config options
```

Sample output

```
Options:
  --prefix=path              path to install hydra and its datafiles to
  --fhs                      install according to the File System Hierarchy Standard
  --with-oracle=prefix       prefix for oracle include dir
  --with-oracle-lib=prefix   prefix for oracle lib dir
  --with-ssl=prefix          prefix for SSL headers
  --with-ssl-lib=prefix      prefix for SSL libraries
  --disable-xhydra           disable compilation of hydra GUI
  --nostrip                  do not per default strip binaries before install
  --debug                    show debug output to trace errors
  --help                     this her
```

So therefore
do
    ./configure #It should autodetect SSL, and you can check in the output
else
    ./configure --with-ssl=SSL LOCATION --with-ssl-lib=SSL LIB LOCATION
then
    make
    make install

This is the general way of compiling a program from source, and you should learn how these steps work for future use.